# port 80 in use? on MAC

Tags: node.js, ports

I'm trying to run my node server on my Macbook in port 80 and it keeps giving me this error:

`EADDRINUSE : Looks like port 80 is in use`

When I run `sudo lsof -i :80`, I get this:

`COMMAND     PID                 USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google     7978 worklaptop  168u  IPv4 0x2cc8fb4019190baf      0t0  TCP 10.0.98.217:56534->151.101.32.188:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google     7978 worklaptop  170u  IPv4 0x2cc8fb4020e369bf      0t0  TCP 10.0.98.217:56535->151.101.32.188:http (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     45908                 root   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     45914               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     45915               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     45916               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     45917               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     45918               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     46011               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     46027               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     46028               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     46029               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     46030               daemon   10u  IPv6 0x2cc8fb3ffd315087      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`

When I kill the Google processes, it just shuts down my Chrome browser..  Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

It's the `apache2` webserver. It comes by default with MacOS.

You can stop it by issuing this command in terminal `sudo apachectl stop`

Also you can permenentaly disable it by command 
`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Comment: Thanks!  Will this mess anything up?  What is the point of the apache2 webserver?

Comment: apache2 webserver is for hosting websites. If you are not running anything locally, you can safely disable it.